# local connection timed out after 120000 while reading the the image from the remote server

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application in BlackBerry 5.0 and want to display an image from a url. While reading the image from the url using the httpconnection I get the exception "local connection timed out after 120000 "

The exception occurs on the line "httpConnection.getResponseCode()".

My code is as follows :

```
private byte[] getimagefromurl(String PhotoUrl)
{

   String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/Folder/xyz.jpg";
   try 
   {
        httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
         System.out.println("url>>>>>>>> "+url);
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
         System.out.println("Response>>>>>>>> "+String.valueOf(httpConnection.getResponseCode()));
        if(httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) 
        {

            InputStream input = httpConnection.openInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int j = 0;
            while((j=input.read()) != -1)
            {
                baos.write(j);
            }
            byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();

        }    
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println("in catch>>>>"+e.toString());
   }
   return byteArray;               
}
```

Answer (score 2):

append  url extension  like following example is work when you r working with WIFI

```
 httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+";interface=wifi", Connector.READ_WRITE);
```

extensions just check this url 
[connection extensions](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the answer is exactly that. The connection timed out. check that your webservice works. if you are testing from device or emulator ,make sure you can hit the URL from the default blackberry browser.

If you are testing in the emulator, make sure you have MDS-CS simulator started.

have a look at this bit of code which works

```
import java.io.InputStream; 
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;

public class HTTPClient {
  public static String getPage(String url) {
    String response = "";

    try {
        StreamConnection s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);

        InputStream input = s.openInputStream();

        byte[] data = new byte[256];
        int len = 0;
        StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();

        while( -1 != (len = input.read(data))) {
            raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
        }

        response = raw.toString();

        input.close();
        s.close();
    } catch(Exception e) { }

    return response;
    }
}
```